# Why "dict[String(aUint16)] = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)" failed in some cases?

Tags: ios, swift

My code, which use [SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html):

```
func simplePing(_ pinger: SimplePing, didSendPacket packet: Data, sequenceNumber: UInt16) {
    begin[String(sequenceNumber)] = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)//AppDelegate.swift:185
    print("Send: \(Common.startCount)")
}
```

It works perfectly in my simulator and iPhone, but after made it available on AppStore, I received about 20 crash logs with some error like that:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  1
...
Thread 1 name:
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   ME                              0x0011e5cc specialized AppDelegate.simplePing(SimplePing, didSendPacket : Data, sequenceNumber : UInt16) -> () + 652 (AppDelegate.swift:185)
1   ME                              0x00116990 @objc AppDelegate.simplePing(SimplePing, didSendPacket : Data, sequenceNumber : UInt16) -> () + 68
2   ME                              0x00116818 @objc AppDelegate.simplePing(SimplePing, didSendPacket : Data, sequenceNumber : UInt16) -> () + 40
3   ME                              0x000f3348 -[SimplePing sendPingWithData:] + 640 (SimplePing.m:297)
...
```

I can't reproduce that crash, so I have to analysis that line of the code:

#### begin[String(sequenceNumber)]

`begin` initialized with `begin = [String: Int]()`, so its type is `[String : Int]`, and `sequenceNumber`'s type is `UInt16`. So I think `begin[String(sequenceNumber)]` doesn't have any potential bug.

#### Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)

And `Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)` is just something like `Int(aDouble * 1000)`, it seems correct in any situation.

So I get really confused with that crash log, could anyone please give me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for `Int`:

> On 32-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int32, and on 64-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int64.

A signed 32-bit integer has a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.

At the moment, `Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)` returns a value of 1,495,855,170,970.

That is significantly larger than what will fit in a 32-bit integer.

The crash is being caused by the overflow you are attempting when casting the `Double` to an `Int` when run on a 32-bit iOS device.

I would suggest an explicit use of `Int64` instead of `Int`:

```
begin[String(sequenceNumber)] = Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

Comment: Is there any way to test it with a 32-bit simulator? I have no 32-bit iOS device...

Comment: I'm not positive but the iPhone 4s simulator might be 32-bit.

Comment: In iPhone 4s simulator reproduces that bug, thank you!

Comment: iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 are 32-bit (both the real devices and in the Simulator). iPhone 5s and later are 64-bit.